# Oracle SQL - Return value only when = X

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to return the SKU_id, only when Zone_1 equals Prod. If, the SKU_ID has multiple Zone_id then i do not wish these records to be returned.

Linked image shows the table, here i would like to return the SKU_ID 'ANS' as it only exists in 'Prod'. Flights wouldn't be returned as it exists in 'STD'`enter code here` also.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT SKU_ID, ZONE_1 FROM INVENTORY
WHERE zone_1 = 'PROD'
```

The issue with this code is that it returns the SKU even if it exists in STD because i'm not sure how to return it where it only exists in zone_1 = 'prod'.

[image: example here]

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SKU_ID
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY SKU_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN zone_1 <> 'PROD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select i.*
from INVENTORY i
where not exists (select 1 
                  from INVENTORY i1 
                  where i1.sku_id = i.sku_id and 
                        i1.zone_1 <> 'PROD'
                  );
```

Comment: The i1 and t.sku confused me here. not sure what they are reference to?

Comment: @KBailey. . . It is typo nothing else.

Comment: @Alex Poole. . . Yes. Thanks